# + Create a new launcher here

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I'm not exactly sure why, but the create launcher function has stopped working for me on Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon 4.0.9.  I created one yesterday to a website, it took me a bit to figure out that I had to put "firefox" or "google-chrome" before the web address. It worked perfectly.  Now today, when I right-click Desktop and click on + Create a new launcher here nothing happens.  The little box where you can put name, command doesn't appear anywhere.  Has anyone experienced this.  Any ideas?

Edit: I found out a workaround with these two commands in terminal.

sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel

and

gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new

The second command gave me a Gtk-message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent.  This is discouraged.

I don't know what that means, or why I need a workaround in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello to both VernonB and user9441393.  It seems that this now a known problem and has been fixed but not pushed out yet.  When I read your question and the solution user9441303 provided I went and looked on the Linuxmint.com web site Forum Search.  Querying on "Create a new launcher" took me here:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=285866&p=1580985&hilit=create+a+new+launcher&sid=38042d40ed04ba48af17b11e5d1e7c37#p1580985

There is an answer from smurphos who is a level 9 contributor.  Here is his answer for your edification.

**"it's a bug - https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/8275 - already fixed in the source, but no update issued yet.
You can apply the fix in advance of the update via the instructions in this post - viewtopic.php?p=1578018#p1578018**

Please note that I have not tried his fix, but I'm sure it works and will be patched for us in the near future.

This is a great place to post questions.  Someone is always looking for an answer to the same question I have.  For the record, there are a number of ways to create a desktop launcher, yet having such a convenient tool in the Cinnamon right-click menu is neat.

Comment: I will definitely try this tomorrow and report back here if it works. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks so much, the patch worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

From the main cinnamon menu, Right click on the menu icon --> configure --> Menu tab --> Open the menu editor --> New Item. It works for me. Then, when you finish with launcher in menu, simply open menu and add link on the desktop or panel.

Comment: I found another way to create launcher - from the main cinnamon menu.
Right click on the menu icon --> configure --> Menu tab --> Open the menu editor --> New Item.

it works for me. 
then, when you finish with launcher in menu, simply open menu and add link on the desktop or panel.